# Get $post Object from another page

Tags: pages, query-posts

This is a rather simple question, so I'll keep it short.

Update1: In this context `{page-structure}` means just that: `page1/page1-1/page1-1-1/{...}`.

Update2: For further clarification, I want to do about the same [the ACF Post Object field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/) is doing, except I want to do it dynamically based on the URL structure as explained below.

I'm making a custom multilingual site, with a dual page structure (with and without `/en`). Any page at `mysite.com/en/{page-structure}` are getting its locale changed to `en_US` and the content (ACF) is fetched from the corresponding page at `mysite.com/{page-structure}`. Based on the locale different content is displayed.

How can I on `mysite.com/en/{page-structure}` automatically get the $post Object from `mysite.com/{page-structure}` (i.e. without `en/`)?

(Currently I'm using ACF to fetch fields from the corresponding page by rewriting the field requests, but it I could change the $post Object on the fly, it would make everything a little simpler.)

Comment: What's adding the `/en`? Is it a plugin? A parent page? A different WordPress install?

Comment: without knowing the contents of `{page-structure}` it's going to be very difficult to know how to answer this question, especially with the `/en/` thing, is that a multilingual plugin? A parent page? How will you know which page it is you want? slug? ID? Please edit your question with more context/details

Comment: Question is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can get the post object of a page with a matching path, minus the `/en` part:

```
$page_path = get_page_uri( get_queried_object_id() ); // en/page/child-page
$target_page_path = str_replace( 'en/', '', $page_path ); // page/child-page
$target_page = get_page_by_path( $target_page_path ); // WP_Post of target page.
```

Comment: I think @anton-lukin also had a correct answer, but this is simpler – marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the question, the right answer would be to use [url_to_postid](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) function.

Then you can setup post id this way:

```
global $post; 
$post = get_post($post_id, OBJECT);
setup_postdata($post);

// your code

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Ok, with this method I think I can retrieve the ID from the page I want. Now that I have the ID, how do redefine the $post Object to display the data from the page?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$global` in before your `$post`

For example:

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. I've updated it and tried to clarify.